# Using Web Browser to access Azure AD secured Web API

Tags: browser, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I've been working on getting a native app to work with a Web API secured by Azure AD using these two sites:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/

http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/12/secure-asp-net-web-api-2-azure-active-directory-owin-middleware-adal/

I would like to use a Web Browser to test out the Web API though, and can't figure out how to enable Browser support to the Azure secured AD.  I'm pretty new at this, so any help would be appreciated.  Is it possible to do have both authentication scenarios (native app, and web browser)?

I know I could make a web application that accesses the Web API, but I was hoping that I could hit the Web API endpoint directly in a browser, and then be forwarded to the Azure AD endpoint for authorization.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This sample should help with hitting the WebAPI directory from a browser:

https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet

Comment: That would not be hitting the WebAPI URI in the browser though, that's using an intermediary to visit the WebAPI.  I have a feeling I'm not going be able to directly hit the WebAPI URI without some sort of intermediary.  

Thanks for the suggestion!